# Can a swift issue a compiler error based on a let constant's value?

Tags: swift

In the sample code below, when the struct is initialized `moreData` takes an enum case to indicate whether additional content is required when accessing its content `data`.

Two functions therefore exist to access the content.  One requires the additional content, so it should not be usable if the `moreData` flag is set to `.notAllowed`, the other does not take additional data so should not be usable is the `moreData` flag is set to `.required`.  A third case of `.allowed` can use either function.

Is there a way to force Xcode to show a compiler error when the wrong function is used?

It seems something it should be able to do, as it is a constant and set whenever the struct is initialized, so its state should be inferable from reading the code.

However the only options I can see are to simply hope the user just gets it right otherwise throw a runtime error.  Or return an optional to allow the code to guard for whether or not the function was able to return usable data.

```
struct Example {

    public enum Permissions {
        case required
        case allowed
        case notAllowed
    }

    let data: String
    let moreData: Permissions

    init(_ data: String, moreData: Permissions = .notAllowed) {
        self.data = data
        self.moreData = moreData
    }

    public func value() -> String {
        // if moreData != .required {
            return data
        // }
        // A compiler error should appear is moreData is .required
    }

    public func value(with extraData: String) -> String {
        // if moreData != .notAllowed {
            return data + " " + extraData
        // }
        // A compiler error should appear if moreData is . notAllowed
    }

}

let example1 = Example("A String")
let example2 = Example("My name is", moreData: .required)

let value1 = example1.value()
// returns "A String"

let value2 = example2.value(with: "Rebecka")
// returns "My name is Rebecka"

let value3 = example1.value(with: "Extra data")
// This should be a compiler error, as moreData is .notAllowed
// The extra data could just be ignored, but…

let value4 = example2.value()
// …there is no work around for this error as extra data is .required
```

Update: I think my example may be a bit too simplified as the use case so I just wanted to detail an example.  One use of the struct is to store keys in a constants file to avoid using strings and the associated risks.  These can be stored in an enum or struct as static let statements.

```
struct Keys {
   static let stringKey = Example("stringKey")
}

func accessData(with key: Keys) -> String {
   // Preparation code
   let result = actualAccessFunction(for: key.value())
   // Process data
   return processedResult
}
```

And where `moreData` is required it may not simply be to  append two strings, but may be used to provide something that will be used to reformat the `data` in a particular way, or to hash or abbreviate it.

But `moreData` should be something that needs to be computed whenever a call is made, otherwise the final computed form of `data` could just be stored instead.  So, to me, it would not make sense to have to separately store the `moreData` value as it would have to be changed before every call to `.value()`

Comment: You should look into [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations#Associated-Values) for enums.

Comment: It seems now like you should be using localized strings, with format strings for the ones that need extra info interpolated.

Comment: At least with what I am currently any changes to the strings will be computed rather than to other fixed strings.  But I am trying to make something generic to allow the same design can be reused for other purposes.  So although this method works well for my needs, I was hoping I could build in compiler checks to ensure the `.value(with:)` and `.value()` functions cannot be used when the definition should not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a construct for exactly this case: You can add associated values to enum cases (As HangerRash mentioned in their comment.)

(Google "Swift enum associated values". You should find a number of tutorials on the subject, or Apple's Swift eBook covers the subject pretty well.)

Give your `.required` case an associated value that holds your data.

Comment: I cannot see how they would fit the situation, but maybe I made my example too simple that it is unclear what I am doing?  The idea of the `Example` struct is that it holds an immutable value while moreData is a computed value that may be required when when accessing the value, so it does not need storing.  For example this struct could be defined with `static let`s in an enum or struct for use as keys, some a fixed string but others requiring a timestamp.  And it may not be a simple append, or even a string, but a value to be used to affect the outcome in some way.